Help identifying a childhood bicycle (early 80s)
This is really just for my own interest, but this was my first "proper" bike as a kid. It weighed about the same as a small family car, and in pretty poor condition by the time I got my hands on it, but I don't remember seeing anything else like it at the time (early-mid 80s) and I loved it.
Unfortunately this is the only photo I have of it, and I can't make out the decals or other crucial details.
Things I remember (and you can see from the pic):

Front shocks
Some sort of hub brake in the front
I think it had 3-speed, twist-grip gears, like a Grifter
The seat was heavy and well padded

I'm starting to think this might have been a frankenbike, as extensive googling/forum posting hasn't turned anything up. But a part of me wants to believe this was a genius example of an ahead-of-its-time mountain bike aimed at kids. Please put me out of my misery one way or another :)
EDIT: The wording on the down tube could well be "TRECKER", and the badge on the front looks like it could be a dark-coloured shield


Well there's a bunch of distinctive features, so it should stand out from the bulk.  Mixte top-tubes is rare on BMX style bikes, as is any form of suspension especially in this era.  The dual-crown fork looks inspired by moto-cross bikes.    Are you absolutely positive of the early-mid 80's time window?

Can you share what country you were in at the time?

I read "TRUGRE" on the down tube, clearly not correct but what  does everyone else read ?

@Criggie hmm, my best guess actually would be '84-'86, judging by my age on the rest of the photo. Fairly confident it wouldn't have been later than '86. But the bike was already a few years old by then. This was in the UK

It does not look frankenbike to me. Frame color matching forks with black matching color handlebars, fenders, brake levers and cables look original. This falls into the motorcycle looking bicycle category. I've searched and found nothing close - just like OP. Lack of any kind of match on such a distinctive bike makes me think they didn't make a lot of them, maybe a special build for a particular store / vender in the UK. -Paul, is there anyone else you can ask who might remember more details?

@DavidD I think you're probably right, it was maybe just a small run to test the market, something like that. Would love to know more about it. My dad bought it from a family who lived near us - if I can just remember who they are, I might be able to get in touch :)

@Criggie thanks for the "TRUGRE" clue. I've been looking at the wording again and the word "TRECKER" is ringing a bell - it would seem to fit. Still not helping me find much on google though

@PaulNearney   Not a direct match, but "TRAKER" make BMX frames with twin top tubes.  See https://bmxmuseum.com/forums/viewtopic.php?pid=6218094 for some bikes that could be cousins.  Still related, but not close.  Its a lead.   https://oldschoolmags.com/tests/Traker_BMXA8112.pdf    and   https://bmxmuseum.com/bikes/traker/   Some of them have kinks in the chain stays but more toward the top than yours.

have you looked here?
https://bmxmuseum.com/
